# Multiple functions with form_dropdown for some checked checkboxes in Codeigniter

Tags: function, codeigniter, checkbox

I want to apply some functions to multiple checked checkboxes using form_dropdown in Codeigniter. I want to have delete, activate and deactivate functions for some selected data. How can I write this code in Codeigniter. Can somebody help me ?!

Comment: You were not supposed to write a comment below something you didn't want to help !

Comment: You were not supposed to ask an unanswerable question :P

Comment: Sounds like your gonna have some kind of behaviors, so your best route would be to use javascript.

Comment: Are there any sources that I can use ?! I couldn't find anything on the net!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define some JavaScript functions that you then attach to each of your dropdowns. This isn't the exact code, http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/165476/#792072 but it illustrates how you can pass a fourth parameter to form_dropdown, which would let you add an onChange attribute that could execute a function.

```
form_dropdown('field_name', $options, $selected, 'onchange="doSomething(this)"');
```

Alternatively, you could use JavaScript to bound the action to the drop downs on load. Either way, you should be able to give each drop down a different action this way.